# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController -

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, androidx

I have `viewpager` with multiple pages whose count depends on response.
Each fragment has recyclerview with grid items. Looks like while setting viewpager app crashes.
I'm not able to trace why crash is happening and line number.

Code:

```
 adapter = new NewCatPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), categoriesResponse.categories);
        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesResponse.categories.size(); i++) {
            NewCategoriesFragment3 categoriesFragment = new NewCategoriesFragment3();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(IntentParams.CATEGORIES_POSITION, i);
            bundle.putBoolean(IntentParams.IS_FOR_RESULT, isForResult);
            bundle.putBoolean(IntentParams.IS_CROSS_BORDER, isCrossBorder);
            categoriesFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            adapter.addFragment(categoriesFragment);
        }
        setUpCategoryTitle(categoriesResponse.categories);


        vpPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        vpPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        vpPager.setPageMargin(12);
        vpPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(categoriesResponse.categories.size());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2560)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2553)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:828)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1863)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:256)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1185)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3083)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2146)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7768)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

NewCatPagerAdapter:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



// Extend from SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter now instead for more dynamic ViewPager items
public class NewCatPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Category> titleList = new ArrayList<>();


    public NewCatPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Category> titleList) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.titleList = titleList;
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList.get(position).displayName;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is related to fragment attachment not related to viewpager.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned it.. It was working fine.. suddenly it started giving error..

Comment: Please share `NewCatPagerAdapter` source code.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your Adapter implementation, maybe there is something wrong in your Activity implementation. For example if you call `super.onCreate` method twice in your activity, you will get a similar exception.

Comment: No I'm not calling super.onCreate twice

Comment: Have you recently updated any components? I've just diagnosed a different Fragment related problem as being triggered by upgrading to androidx.fragment to 1.1.0-beta01 or beyond.
I wasn't even including that library directly, the updated version was pulled in by updating library that relied on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what `NewCatPagerAdapter` is, but the value of `categoriesResponse.categories.size()` does not consider, that there is a current page:

```
vpPager.setOffscreenPageLimit((adapter.getCount() > 1 ? adapter.getCount() - 1 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing I am trying to find out your problem, but works fine in my side!
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager vpPager;
    CatPagerAdapter adapter;
    List<String>list  = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vpPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        list.add("Three");
        list.add("Four");
        list.add("Five");
        adapter = new CatPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            FirstFragment categoriesFragment = new FirstFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            adapter.addFragment(categoriesFragment);
        }
        //setUpCategoryTitle(categoriesResponse.categories);


        vpPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        vpPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        vpPager.setPageMargin(12);
        vpPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class CatPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CatPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, List<String>list) {

        super(fm);
        titleList = list;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "";
    }

}
```